# Solve $0 = \lambda \arctan(t) + \sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In [Bounding solutions of $x' = \lambda \arctan(t) + \sin(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253971/bounding-solutions-of-x-lambda-arctant-sinx) the person who answered worked with so-called nullclines of the equation. That is the solutions to $0 = \lambda \arctan(t) + \sin(x)$. In our interest was to discuss the case $- \frac 2 \pi< \lambda < \frac 2 \pi$.

If I try to solve the equation  $0 = \lambda \arctan(t) + \sin(x)$, then I come straight forward to $x = \arcsin(-\lambda \arctan(t)) + 2 k \pi = - \arcsin(\lambda \arctan(t)) + 2 k \pi$ where I take care that this is well defined since $- \frac 2 \pi< \lambda < \frac 2 \pi$.

However, there is another solution, namely $x = \arcsin(\lambda \arctan(t)) + \pi + 2 k \pi$. How does one derive this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose a branch of $\arcsin x$, namely assuming $x \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, but you could have chosen another.

Comment: which choice would lead to the other solution?

Comment: @Javier When we define $\arcsin x$ we must select an interval where $\sin x$ is injective, and the default choice is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. But for instance $\sin x$ is also injective in $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3 \pi}{2}]$ and you could define the inverse function for that interval. The values will be shifted by $\pi$ with respect to the usual $\arcsin$.